# $(a_n)$ is a cauchy sequence, show that there exists a sequence $(a_{n_k}) \subseteq (a_n)$ such that $|a_{n_{k+1}} - a_{n_k} | < \frac{1}{2^k}$

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-sequences

### let $(a_n)$ be a cauchy sequence, show that there exists a sequence such that $(ax_{n_k}) \subseteq (a_n)$ such that $|a_{n_{k+1}} - a_{n_k} | < \frac{1}{2^k}$ for all $k$

since $a_n$ is cauchy we know that it converges,bounded and according to bolzano-weierstrass theorem we know that there exists a convergent sub sequence.

and according to cauchy definition a sequence $a_n$ is cauchy for any positive real number $\varepsilon$ there exists $N \in \Bbb N$ such that for all $n,m>N$ $|a_n-a_m| < \varepsilon$

I think that I need to construct a subsequence $a_{n_k}$ till I get to $|a_{n_{k+1}} - a_{n_k} | < \frac{1}{2^k}$ but I am having a hard time actually applying it

I thought about choosing an $\varepsilon$ each time for example if $\varepsilon = \frac{1}{2}$ that for $N_1$ we get $ |a_m-a_n| < \frac{1}{2}$ but I am not sure how to actually go on with this and how to conduct the proof

Thanks for any tips and help

Comment: Hint: If the limit is $\alpha$, consider  $|a_{n_k} - \alpha|$. Wishful Thinkingly, how large would we want this to be, in order to force out the condition of the problem?

Comment: Maybe I am wrong (because I have actually not worked it out in detail) but for every $\epsilon_k = 1/2^k$, you can get $N_k$ such that any two indices from $A_k = {N_k+1,N_k+2,.....}$ will satisfy the requirement for $1/2^k$. This sequence of sets are decreasing as in $A_1 \supset A_2 \supset A_3 ...$ which I think necessarily means $N_1 < N_2 < N3 ...$ Choosing the first index of $A_k \cap A_{k+1}$ should then give you the required subsequence. Let me know if there is an error in this logic and I will remove this comment.